# i am trying to display certain items on a page, but i have a problem with the if statement

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I am trying to display items that have their warehouse field == to the warehouse name, so if the warehouse they are seeing has the same name as the warehouse field of the item they should see the items. I tried the following but it isn't working.

```
{% for item in items %}
        {% if item.warehouse == warehouse.name %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.box_quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Quantity_in_box }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.supplier }}</td>   
        <td>{{ item.expiry }}</td>       
        <td>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button"> Edit</a>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"> x</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

when i remove the if statement as follows

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.box_quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Quantity_in_box }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.supplier }}</td>   
        <td>{{ item.expiry }}</td>       
        <td>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button"> Edit</a>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"> x</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

i get to see all the items.

related view

```
def Warehouse(request, pk):
   Warehouse = warehouse.objects.get(id=pk)
items = item.objects.all()

context = {
    'items': items,
    'warehouse': Warehouse,
}

return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/warehouse.html', context)
```

related url

```
path('warehouse/<str:pk>/', Warehouse, name="warehouse"),
```

complete html

```
{% extends 'Inventory_Management/layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

<br>

<h4>Currently Viewing {{ warehouse.name }}</h4>                                                                    
  <a href="{% url 'warehouses' %}" role="button">Back To Warehouses</a>
      <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Box_Q</th>
        <th>Q_in_box</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Expiry</th>
        <th><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/add/" role="button" 
     class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Add</a></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    {% for item in items %}
        {% if item.warehouse == warehouse.name %}
           <tr>
           <td>{{ item.pk }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.box_quantity }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.Quantity_in_box }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.supplier }}</td>   
           <td>{{ item.expiry }}</td>       
           <td>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/" class="btn btn-warning 
            btn-sm" role="button"> Edit</a>
            <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Inventory_Management/item/" class="btn btn-danger 
            btn-sm" role="button"> x</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

complete urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index"),
    path('warehouses', warehouses, name="warehouses"),
    path('warehouse/<str:pk>/', Warehouse, name="warehouse"),
    path('customerHome', customerHome, name="customerHome"),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', Customer, name="customer"),
    path('admin/Inventory_Management/warehouse/<str:pk>/', Warehouse, name="change"),
    path('add_new_warehouse', add_new_warehouse, name="Nwarehouse"),
    path('add_item', add_item, name="Nitem"),
    path("display_search", search, name='display_search'),
   ]
```

complete views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def search(request):
   items = item.objects.all()
   name_q = request.GET.get('name')
   box_quantity_q = request.GET.get('box_quantity')
   Quantity_in_box_q = request.GET.get('quantity_in_box')
   code_q = request.GET.get('code')
   price_q = request.GET.get('price')
   expiry_q = request.GET.get('expiry')
   supplier_q = request.GET.get('supplier')
   warehouse_q = request.GET.get('warehouse')
   category_q = request.GET.get('category')
   date_created_ = request.GET.get('date_created')
   if warehouse_q != '' and warehouse_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(warehouse__name__icontains=warehouse_q)
   if date_created_ != '' and date_created_ is not None:
      items = items.filter(date_created__icontains=date_created_)
   if name_q != '' and name_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(name__icontains=name_q)
   if price_q != '' and price_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(price__icontains=price_q)
   if box_quantity_q != '' and box_quantity_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(box_quantity__icontains=box_quantity_q)
   if Quantity_in_box_q != '' and Quantity_in_box_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(Quantity_in_box__icontains=Quantity_in_box_q)
   if code_q != '' and code_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(code__icontains=code_q)
   if category_q != '' and category_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(category__name__icontains=category_q)
   if supplier_q != '' and supplier_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(supplier__name__icontains=supplier_q)
   if expiry_q != '' and expiry_q is not None:
      items = items.filter(expiry__icontains=expiry_q)
   context = {
     'items' : items,
    }
   return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/search.html', context)

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/index.html')

def warehouses(request):
  Warehouses = warehouse.objects.all()

   context = {
      'warehouses': Warehouses,
   }

  return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/warehouses.html', context)

  def Customer(request, pk):
   orders = order.objects.all()
   Customer = customer.objects.get(id=pk)

   context = {
      'orders': orders,
      'customer': Customer,
  }
 return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/customer.html', context)

def customerHome(request):
   orders = order.objects.all()
   customers = customer.objects.all()
   context = {
      'orders': orders,
      'customers': customers,
   }
 return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/customerHome.html', context)

def Warehouse(request, pk):
   Warehouse = warehouse.objects.get(id=pk)
   items = item.objects.all()

   context = {
     'items': items,
     'warehouse': Warehouse,
   }

    return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/warehouse.html', context)

def add_item(request):
   return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/')

   def add_new_warehouse(request):
   form = WarehouseForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = WarehouseForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('warehouses')

   context = {
     'form': form,
   }

  return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/add_new_warehouse.html', context)
```

related models

```
class item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
  box_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  Quantity_in_box = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  expiry = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  supplier = models.ForeignKey(supplier, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  warehouse = models.ForeignKey(warehouse, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  category = models.ForeignKey(category, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class warehouse(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

full models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.contrib import admin

class warehouse(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class supplier(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False)
  email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

 class order_header(models.Model):
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  User = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default="Seller")
  Type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="cash")
  Buyer = models.ForeignKey(customer, blank=True, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  Note = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="Discount: ")
  Order_Id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
  editable=False)

def __str__(self):
    return 'Order Id: {self.Order_Id}'.format(self=self)

 class item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
  box_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  Quantity_in_box = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  expiry = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  supplier = models.ForeignKey(supplier, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  warehouse = models.ForeignKey(warehouse, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  category = models.ForeignKey(category, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class order(models.Model):
  order_head = models.ForeignKey(order_header, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  items = models.ForeignKey(item, blank=False, null=True, 
  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  Quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
  total = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return 'Order Customer: {self.order_head.Buyer}'.format(self=self)
```

help, appreciated! please help!

Comment: Please share your models, at first sight it should be `{% if item.warehouse == warehouse %}`

Comment: i will share them now

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, you are awesome i tried what you said and it is working, but please can i ask you to explain for me? i don't really understand why it is working. thank you very much!

Comment: i kind of get it now, i guess it is because in my models.py the warehouse model return its name which is then compared to the name of the warehouse of the item, i guess i get it. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!